# Why is map traversal sequential?

Tags: go, hash, hashmap

Isn't that out of order output 
QAQ

this is my code

```
var i=map[int]int{
   1:1,
   2:2,
   3:3,
}
for i2, i3 := range i {
       fmt.Println(i2, i3)
}
```

and the output is

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

why?

Comment: It's just "pseudo random" and it happens that the insert sequence 1:1, 2:2, 3:3 ends up iterating in the original order (which may be specific for even just the Go version you're running). Try inserting for example 1:1, 3:3, 2:2 instead and it won't necessarily iterate in the insert order.

Comment: thanks a lot. I understood

Comment: `1 2 3` is one of the possible random orderings of `1 2 3`

Comment: But I experimented seven or eight times with this set of data, and the results were the same.

Comment: @sexy_Robber:  "I experimented seven or eight times." Just because you toss a coin 7 or 8 times and it is always heads doesn't mean that the probability is not 0.5. For a small number, using a pseudo random number generator (PRNG), it's not surprising. Keep running the program: https://play.golang.org/p/yjAOalbsOOI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go maps do not guarantee iteration order. In fact, the order may change from one iteration to the other, and the order of insertion and type-specific value order is not relevant. More info here:

https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action

Comment: however,When I say so, the results of the five or six repetitions remain unchanged.

Comment: Iteration order *may* change doesn't mean it *will* change.

Comment: i know,thanks a lot